# Print message when loop fails

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to understand why I cannot print my desired outcome. I have changed my loop logic around a few times but cannot see the issue.

I have an array list `ArrayList<Landing> landings = new ArrayList<>();`

I have the following method in the `Landing` class to check the landing ID;

```
public boolean checkId(int id) {
    if (this.landingId == id) {
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am trying to create some input handling where if the user inputs an ID which doesn't match an ID in the array list, an error message is printed. I can't seem to get the failed scenario to print the message

```
System.out.print("Please enter the landing ID: ");
            int id = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            boolean unsuccessful = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < landings.size(); i++) {

                if (landings.get(i).checkId(id)) {
                    landings.get(i).printLandings();
                    unsuccessful = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    unsuccessful = true;

                }
            }

            if (unsuccessful) {
                System.out.println(
                        "\nThe ID you enterred does not match any landing");

            }
break;
```

TIA

Comment: `break` in the `if` branch will just end at the first *successful* condition. You should break when you set `unsuccessful` to true, instead. Otherwise the next successful condition will just reset the boolean, break the loop and skip the message.

Comment: Unrelated, but `checkId` can be simplified to `return this.landingId == id;`

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca That is the desired outcome for a successful ID match. However, if it fails, it needs to print the message once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if there's "any" (= at least one) match, you gotta start with `boolean unsuccessful = true`.

Let's look at the simplest case: When the `List` is empty, the loop won't run a single time. Though `unsuccessful` will not be changed and has to set to `true` before the loop.

Here's a simplified version.

```
boolean unsuccessful = true
for(...) {
  if(matchFound) {
    unsuccessful = false;
    break;
  }
}

if(unsuccessful) { print(...); }
```

Maybe you should also consider renaming the variable to `success` (at least for me that's easier to read):

```
boolean success = false;
for(...) {
  if(matchFound) {
    success = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(!success) { print(...); }
```

As you can see, you also don't need the `else` part anymore.

Comment: Legend! Thanks @Benjamin M for the explanation and helping simplify. Working well now

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following if you use Java 8 or above,

```
Optional<Landing> landing = landings.stream().filter(i -> i.checkId(id)).findFirst();
landing.ifPresent(Landing::printLandings);
boolean unsuccessful = !landing.isPresent();
```

Also you can improve checkId method as follows,

```
public boolean checkId(int id) {
        return this.landingId == id;
    }
```

Hope this will sort out your issues. cheers!